# Merging arrays based on a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three numpy arrays:

```
A = np.array([41, 162, 349, 641, 531, 445, 35])
B = np.array([42, 162, 323, 479, 436, 389, 36])
C = np.array([1.4, 7, 14, 28, 70, 140])
```

I would like to generate a fourth array, D, with the same dimensions as A and B that compares each value in A with the maximum value in C taking the value from A if the value in A is less than the maximum value in C and the value from B if the value in A is greater than the maximum value in C. So in this case:

```
np.max(C) = 140
```

and therefore D would be:

```
D = np.array([41, 162, 323, 479, 436, 389, 35])
```

Comment: @Divakar the first element of C is indeed 1.4. If the value from A < maxC and B > maxC then the value from A should always be chosen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is made for that.

```
D = np.where(A<C.max(), A, B)
# [ 41 162 323 479 436 389  35]
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.where()` is probably the preferred solution, as stated by *@Ghilas BELHADJ*. In case you want the list comprehension version (to possibly use without `numpy`)

```
max_c = np.max(C)
D = np.array([A[i] if A[i] < max_c else B[i] for i in range(len(A))])
```